# Apache2 client ip and port

Tags: apache-2.2, log-files

Do anyone know if Apache by default is logging the port number of a client and were to find it. I know that it log the ip, but for mobile users there can be several devices with the same ip which uses a different port.

Comment: The source port of every request is random anyway and doesn't help to differentiate between different clients.

Comment: @Sven The source port is mandatory to trace the source of a connection originating behind Large Scale NAT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Apache doesn't log the port number of the client but it can. Where the logs are is dependent on where you told Apache to log to.

You need to study the [mod_log_config documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html), in particular the [CustomLog directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html#customlog) and the [CustomLogFormats](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats).

Tne documentation is your friend.